# Specified sqlite3 gem not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rubygems

Although I am relatively new to Ruby on Rails, I have been developing apps for a short while now. The problem I seem to have is when I create a new rails app (locally / using c9) I seem to be getting this error when I start up the apache server

```
"Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. 
Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the 
minimum required by ActiveRecord)"
```

In My Gem file I can see that the sqlite3 gem is present.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the sqlite3 gem trying both versions 1.3.13 as well as 1.4.0 but with no success.

I have also 'git cloned' one of my older completed apps from git hub on to my 'local' and c9 development environments and will work perfectly until I bundle update, Then I get the same error message!

Can anyone give me some advise? I am aware that this problem was brought up a few years back but was wondering if anyone has encountered this recently and if/how they resolved this?

Many Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.11'`

Comment: Thanks Kamal, That seems to have done the trick! I have tried this gem on both my local as well as c9 IDE and works !!

Comment: Back in business :)

Comment: I am glad it helped you, I put the answer, kindly accept it by click tick mark beneath arrows, so other people searching can find the answer easily. As in comments we don't focus and can ignore response of it. Thank you.

Comment: Exactly the same problem, but unfortunately the solution didn't work for me.  The error occurs in an initialization file where the app connects to the database `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(configuration[Rails.env])`.  'Rails.env' here is 'production' and 'configuration' is my loaded 'database.yml' file where 'sqlite3' is specified as the adapter: 
`production:  adapter: sqlite3`.  This all used to work.  I tried uninstalling , re-installing, updating, etc, the gem as well as the bundle.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is very strange but two weeks ago I also got the same issue, and when I initiate my `rails new project` it put `gem 'sqlite3'` without any version number, and I get the same error. So I played a lot on brew so I thought it is an issue due to that playing with SQLite, somehow I came to know that maybe my Sqlite3 gem has an issue. And I noticed it is loading 1.4 version of it.

I did following change and it worked.

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.11'
```

Just in case if someone searching answer of this question, as it resolved issue of question asker.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me too!  Rails 4.2.11, ruby-2.6.2.