# Ruby on Rails - sqlite installation problems Windows7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rubygems

I installed ruby (along with development kit) and then I installed rails using the command gem install rails.

I am looking to start a new rails project, however it is throwing an error, and asking to make sure that
`gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/`
succeeds before bundling.

I ran the above command, but I got an error as follows:

[image]

I am following these two links to start a rails project or on how to install SQLite in windows.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

https://skorks.com/2009/08/installing-and-using-sqlite-with-ruby-on-windows/

I also manually downloaded the sqlite files from the sqlite download page and copied them to C:/ruby/bin folder

Looking for a way to start a new project in rails with no sqlite3 issues.

Comment: Already answered in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54653687/specified-sqlite3-gem-not-loaded/54662418#54662418) Just change version of sqlite as per answer.

Comment: @KamalPanhwar Your link worked. Thanks. However - should I keep doing this every time I start the new project? 
Also, I got the error as cannot load such file --- sqlite3/ sqlite3_native <load error>, as I am trying to start the server

Comment: The issue recently came, as Rails is using standard Sqlit3 gem which is not 1.4 but unfortunately it is giving issue, now Rails 6 came and so hope issue resolved. When you create rails project you need to add many Gems, this is just changing one version number that is all.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line into your project Gemfile and `bundle install` again.

```
gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: "add-gemspec"
```

This will fix your problem.

Comment: I do not have git installed. Is this the only way?
Also - should I be doing this whenever I create a new project?

Comment: Bundler has the ability to install gems directly from git repositories. So you just need to do bundle install bundler will handle it.

Comment: No you don't need git just change version of sqlite3 in Gemfile ```gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.11'``` and run ```bundle install```